# Access curve radius value inside Geometry Nodes?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I've searched *a lot* for this. When working with curves I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> a lot to change the radius/scale of certain areas.

But when working with objects along a curve in Geometry Nodes I can't seem to succeed in this.

Is there a way to access that radius value? I put in an example on the screenshot of deforming the mesh with the *Set Position* + *Noise* with a multiplier.

If I had the radius value I could multiply it and change the scale this way. Is there a way to access it?

I'd appreciate the help a lot!

[image: screenshot of current setup]

EDIT: I've tried the Radius node and it does nothing in this setup. I've tried using it in multiple ways to no success.

EDIT 2: Explaining the file. From top to bottom, first it's a normal curve with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> radius changes. Second is the setup that can deform with a noise. Third is the one where nothing happens with the radius node. 4th too. Fifth is the setup with a mesh on a curve, where <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> can change the thickness of the object, which is the result I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

Comment: [Radius Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/read/radius.html)

Comment: Doesn't work like this, when I attach it instead of the noise it does nothing.

Comment: and can u pls provide a simplified blend file with radius node where it doesn't do anything? thx

Comment: [Set Curve Radius Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/curve/write/set_curve_radius.html) ?

Comment: Hi Chris, I updated the file and the description on the question. It's the third of the examples. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Gorgious, do you know how would I use this in this case? I don't think it's what I'm looking for but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: You don't get a radius at this point with the node `Radius` because you don't have a curve anymore, but a mesh. To achieve the desired result, you would have to insert the radius node in the group "X_Curve_Deform" and scale the Vetcor with it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4DLY.png

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much Quellenform. Honestly thought this would become a feature request at this point. Beyond grateful for this solution, you're helping me a lot. :') Would you like to post this as an answer so I can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, the value for *Radius* is not available, because at this point you no longer have a curve, but instead the mesh you created. And there the attribute *Radius* is no longer available.

So the processing has to be done at another place, that is, where you process the mesh together with the curve.

In your example, this is the case in the group "X_Curve_Deform", where you bend the mesh along a curve.

The crucial part here is the node `Sample Curve` with which you get the positions, tangents and normals of the curve at certain points.

This node offers the advantage of additionally sampling an arbitrary value at the desired point, and in your case this is the value provided by the node `Radius`.

In order to transfer these values to the mesh according to your wishes, you would have to scale the offset calculated by you additionally according to this value.

The content of the node "X_Curve_Deform" then looks like this:

[image]

<sub>(The value *Radius* is transferred here with `Sample Index` and at the end the offset is scaled with this value)</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and for formatting the answer. I’m sure this will be helpful for a lot of people. The Blender community is great because of people like you. Cheers! :)